# Getting Circular placeholder reference error for specific key

Tags: java, spring

I am getting Circular reference error if my placeholder key starts with "database"

This config gives error.

```
<bean id="paymentTransactionLogMessageDecoratorDao"
      class="com.gsicommerce.payment.dao.PaymentTransactionLogMessageDecoratorDao">
    <constructor-arg ref="paymentTransactionLogMessageDao"/>
    <constructor-arg value="${database.payments.logging.enabled}"/>
</bean>
```

> Error:   Circular placeholder reference
>   'database.payments.logging.enabled' in property definitions

When we change the key name like this,

```
<bean id="paymentTransactionLogMessageDecoratorDao"
   class="com.gsicommerce.payment.dao.PaymentTransactionLogMessageDecoratorDao">
    <constructor-arg ref="paymentTransactionLogMessageDao"/>
    <constructor-arg value="${payments.database.logging.enabled}"/>
</bean>
```

this works. Do we have any reserve key words ("database") ?

As you can see, its a constructor injection and the property name is completely different.

```
public paymentTransactionLogMessageDecoratorDao(PaymentTransactionLogPersistenceServicetransactionLogMessageDao,
            boolean databaseLoggingEnabled) {
        this.transactionLogPersistenceService = transactionLogMessageDao;
        this.databaseLoggingEnabled = databaseLoggingEnabled;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your are using maven resource filtering: in this case, as detailed in [this post](https://steveschols.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/spring-3-1-unified-property-management-before-and-after/),  the keys of the property value to filter and it’s respective Spring property-placeholder cannot be the same.

Comment: That blog post doesn't refer to Java code: it refers to the property file used by Maven and the XML file used by Spring and says that they must not contain the same identifier..

Comment: In my case, I did not use any property name in the xml file. Instead it is assigned via constructor (as an argument list). Here there are no identifiers used in xml config.

Comment: I don't understand: you have posted a piece of XML with a placeholder, is this placeholder equal to some property key in a file used as a Maven filter?

Comment: Yes, it is read from a property file as => payments.database.logging.enabled=${payments.database.logging.enabled}

Comment: Well, that blog post explains that you cannot do this.  It's not a problem of reserved words, it's a problem of reused identifiers.

Comment: But if you see, If my key starts with "database" it throws error. When I change it to "payments" ( in both places)  as shown it works.

Comment: But you change the indentifier only on the right of the equal sign, right? When the right part is different from the left part it works.

Comment: No I changed both right and left. Even then it works. So basically when i have something starts with " database" it throws error.